# Running `cabal repl` with Top-level Functions

Tags: haskell, cabal

I'm trying to learn to sandbox my Haskell projects with cabal.

I make extensive use of the command interpreter `ghci`, which imports top-level functions by default.

`cabal repl` also provides a command interpreter, but top-level functions are not imported.

How can I run `cabal repl` so that top-level constants and functions will be defined in the command interpreter?

Here's a minimal example:

```
-- somefile.hs
someConstant :: Int
someConstant = 5

main :: IO ()
main = undefined
```

Now, `someConstant` will be defined when I run `ghci somefile.hs`, but it won't be defined when I run `cabal repl`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the module is one listed in your project (i.e. in your exposed-modules or other-modules sections):

```
:m *ModuleName
```

Otherwise:

```
:l somefile.hs
```

See also [What's really in scope at the prompt?](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/interactive-evaluation.html#ghci-scope) from the Fine Documentation.

Comment: I think the file name should also start with the Capital letter as [mentioned here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Modules#Modules).

Comment: New link for "What’s really in scope at the prompt?": https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/users_guide/ghci.html#ghci-scope